# How show check mark icon when TextBox value is valid?

Tags: asp.net, validation, textbox

I have form that use validator like this:

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="v" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Required!" ControlToValidate="phoneNumber" Display="Dynamic"/>
<asp:TextBox ID="phoneNumber" runat="server" class="invite"/>
```

It shows error when `TextBox` value is not valid;now How can I show check mark image when value of `TextBox` is valid dynamically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think. This is not so simple with asp.net validation

I would suggest, use [jquery validation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/). there you will be able to show custom html on validate